# What does OP stand for?

Tags: support

I know OP means the person asking the question. But what does it actually stand for? I only found out the meaning from context.

Comment: Original Poster.

Comment: @Shog9 Did you just edit my comment? Just curious, 'cause I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: I *can* edit your comment, @MikeM. - but in this particular case, I didn't. Looks like one of the moderators capitalized the P.

Comment: Can you remove the whole "I know this seems stupid" part @Shog9 ? It's unnecessary *ya sure* Is this you replying? Cause I was also referring to the title n_n' *fiiiine* thank you

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah, I was coming back to do the same, and thought I was going crazy. I wasn't aware you guys could do that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It's rarely used, and usually only to fix really heinous stuff like the removal of personal insults and grocer's apostrophes.

Comment: Its like an OG, but a poster instead of a gangsta.